# Unique rows while joining tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am running the following query while trying to join 3 tables :

```
select
  a.project_id, a.acc_name, a.project_name, a.iot,a.acc_id, a.active,
  b.app_fte, b.contact_person, c.cost_call_date
from
  Account a, Application b, account_version c
where
  a.acc_id in (Select acc_id from account where acc_name='GGG') and
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c.cost_call_date) = 3;
```

Ideally I should be getting 5 distinct rows but when I am running the above query I am getting 30 rows where each row is getting duplicated 5 times. I have also tried using the distinct keyword but still I get 10 rows where each row is getting duplicated. Please help me in getting unique rows.

Comment: To debug queries, we need 1) tables definition. 2) sample data set. 3) current output. 4) desired output.

Comment: Are you intending to conduct cross joins?

Comment: how are these tables supposed to be related?